# Why does pyautogui's .activate() works fine in CMD but raises exception in VSC or Python Shell?

Tags: python, debugging, pyautogui

I am using `pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle()` to get a Google Chrome window and then `.activate()` it.
The script:

```
import pyautogui

def switch_to_chrome():
    w = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')
    w[0].activate()

def main():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Enter your command:')
        if user_input == 'x':
            switch_to_chrome()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script works fine from CMD but not so from VSC or Python Shell, where it would raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zs\OneDrive\文档\PythonScripts\test2.py", line 101, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\zs\OneDrive\文档\PythonScripts\test2.py", line 98, in main
    switch_to_chrome()
  File "c:\Users\zs\OneDrive\文档\PythonScripts\test2.py", line 92, in switch_to_chrome
    w[0].activate()
  File "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 246, in activate
    _raiseWithLastError()
  File "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 99, in _raiseWithLastError
    raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' % (errorCode, _formatMessage(errorCode)))
pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 6 - 句柄无效。
```

PS: "句柄无效" means Invalid handle. I couldn't find its English version.